# mongodb-kubernetes-operator - mongodb-agent is never ready

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, operators

**What did you do to encounter the bug?
Steps to reproduce the behavior:**

Deploy manager v0.8.2
then MongoDBCommunity v6.0.5

**What did you expect?**
Mongodb-agent ready and cluster OK

**What happened instead?**
Side container mongodb-agent is never go to ready state.

**Errors :**

- Readiness probe failed: command "/opt/scripts/readinessprobe" timed out
- In the mongodbagent log : "Readiness probe failed: panic: open /var/log/mongodb-mms-automation/healthstatus/agent-health-status.json: no such file or directory goroutine 1 [running]: main.main() /workspace/cmd/readiness/main.go:226"
- In the mongodbagent log with readiness probe v1.0.17 instead of v1.0.15 : cat: /mongodb-automation/agent-api-key/agentApiKey: No such file or directory

**Operator Information**
Operator Version : 0.8.2
MongoDB Image used : 6.0.5

**Kubernetes Cluster Information**
Distribution : tkgi
Version : 1.24
Image Registry location (quay, or an internal registry) : quay
Additional context
We try to up the readinessprobe version from 1.0.15 to 1.0.17 but we have the same problem

**MongoDBCommunity YAML : **

```
apiVersion: mongodbcommunity.mongodb.com/v1
kind: MongoDBCommunity
metadata:
  name: mongodb-replicaset
spec:
  members: 1
  type: ReplicaSet
  version: "6.0.5"
  security:
    authentication:
      modes: ["SCRAM"]
  users:
    - name: user-admin
      db: mydb
      passwordSecretRef: # a reference to the secret that will be used to generate the user's password
        name: user-admin-mongo-secret
        key: MONGO_PASSWORD
      roles:
        - name: clusterAdmin
          db: mydb
        - name: dbOwner
          db: mydb
      scramCredentialsSecretName: my-scram
  statefulSet:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: mongod
              resources:
                limits:
                  cpu: "200m"
                  memory: 500M
                requests:
                  cpu: "50m"
                  memory: 100M
            - name: mongodb-agent
              resources:
                limits:
                  cpu: "200m"
                  memory: 250M
                requests:
                  cpu: "50m"
                  memory: 50M
  additionalMongodConfig:
    storage.wiredTiger.engineConfig.journalCompressor: zlib
```

log files for the operator

```
Running ./manager
2023-10-26T14:36:16.874Z    INFO    manager/main.go:74  Watching namespace: my-namespace
I1026 14:36:17.925053       8 request.go:690] Waited for 1.03553922s due to client-side throttling, not priority and fairness, request: GET:https://56.0.0.1:443/apis/tap.linkerd.io/v1alpha1?timeout=32s
2023-10-26T14:36:20.635Z    INFO    manager/main.go:91  Registering Components.
2023-10-26T14:36:20.635Z    INFO    manager/main.go:104 Starting the Cmd.
2023-10-26T14:36:20.737Z    INFO    controllers/replica_set_controller.go:139   Reconciling MongoDB {"ReplicaSet": "my-namespace/mongodb-replicaset"}
2023-10-26T14:36:20.737Z    DEBUG   controllers/replica_set_controller.go:141   Validating MongoDB.Spec {"ReplicaSet": "my-namespace/mongodb-replicaset"}
2023-10-26T14:36:20.737Z    DEBUG   controllers/replica_set_controller.go:151   Ensuring the service exists {"ReplicaSet": "my-namespace/mongodb-replicaset"}
2023-10-26T14:36:20.838Z    DEBUG   agent/agent_readiness.go:106    The Pod 'ds042-mongodb-replicaset-0' doesn't have annotation 'agent.mongodb.com/version' yet    {"ReplicaSet": "my-namespace/mongodb-replicaset"}
2023-10-26T14:36:20.939Z    DEBUG   agent/replica_set_port_manager.go:122   No port change required {"ReplicaSet": "my-namespace/mongodb-replicaset"}
2023-10-26T14:36:21.041Z    INFO    controllers/replica_set_controller.go:470   Create/Update operation succeeded   {"ReplicaSet": "my-namespace/mongodb-replicaset", "operation": "updated"}
2023-10-26T14:36:21.041Z    INFO    controllers/replica_set_controller.go:362   Creating/Updating AutomationConfig  {"ReplicaSet": "my-namespace/mongodb-replicaset"}
2023-10-26T14:36:21.055Z    DEBUG   scram/scram.go:172  Credentials have not changed, using credentials stored in: secret/my-scram-scram-credentials
2023-10-26T14:36:21.055Z    DEBUG   agent/agent_readiness.go:106    The Pod 'ds042-mongodb-replicaset-0' doesn't have annotation 'agent.mongodb.com/version' yet    {"ReplicaSet": "my-namespace/mongodb-replicaset"}
2023-10-26T14:36:21.055Z    DEBUG   agent/replica_set_port_manager.go:122   No port change required {"ReplicaSet": "my-namespace/mongodb-replicaset"}
2023-10-26T14:36:21.055Z    DEBUG   agent/replica_set_port_manager.go:40    Calculated process port map: map[ds042-mongodb-replicaset-0:27017]  {"ReplicaSet": "my-namespace/mongodb-replicaset"}
2023-10-26T14:36:21.055Z    DEBUG   controllers/replica_set_controller.go:537   AutomationConfigMembersThisReconciliation   {"mdb.AutomationConfigMembersThisReconciliation()": 1}
2023-10-26T14:36:21.055Z    DEBUG   controllers/replica_set_controller.go:385   Waiting for agents to reach version 3   {"ReplicaSet": "my-namespace/mongodb-replicaset"}
2023-10-26T14:36:21.055Z    DEBUG   agent/agent_readiness.go:106    The Pod 'ds042-mongodb-replicaset-0' doesn't have annotation 'agent.mongodb.com/version' yet    {"ReplicaSet": "my-namespace/mongodb-replicaset"}
2023-10-26T14:36:21.055Z    INFO    controllers/mongodb_status_options.go:110   ReplicaSet is not yet ready, retrying in 10 seconds
2023-10-26T14:36:21.063Z    INFO    controllers/replica_set_controller.go:139   Reconciling MongoDB {"ReplicaSet": "my-namespace/mongodb-replicaset"}
2023-10-26T14:36:21.063Z    DEBUG   controllers/replica_set_controller.go:141   Validating MongoDB.Spec {"ReplicaSet": "my-namespace/mongodb-replicaset"}
2023-10-26T14:36:21.063Z    DEBUG   controllers/replica_set_controller.go:151   Ensuring the service exists {"ReplicaSet": "my-namespace/mongodb-replicaset"}
2023-10-26T14:36:21.063Z    DEBUG   agent/agent_readiness.go:106    The Pod 'ds042-mongodb-replicaset-0' doesn't have annotation 'agent.mongodb.com/version' yet    {"ReplicaSet": "my-namespace/mongodb-replicaset"}
2023-10-26T14:36:21.063Z    DEBUG   agent/replica_set_port_manager.go:122   No port change required {"ReplicaSet": "my-namespace/mongodb-replicaset"}
2023-10-26T14:36:21.167Z    INFO    controllers/replica_set_controller.go:470   Create/Update operation succeeded   {"ReplicaSet": "my-namespace/mongodb-replicaset", "operation": "updated"}
2023-10-26T14:36:21.167Z    INFO    controllers/replica_set_controller.go:362   Creating/Updating AutomationConfig  {"ReplicaSet": "my-namespace/mongodb-replicaset"}
2023-10-26T14:36:21.180Z    DEBUG   scram/scram.go:172  Credentials have not changed, using credentials stored in: secret/my-scram-scram-credentials
2023-10-26T14:36:21.180Z    DEBUG   agent/agent_readiness.go:106    The Pod 'ds042-mongodb-replicaset-0' doesn't have annotation 'agent.mongodb.com/version' yet    {"ReplicaSet": "my-namespace/mongodb-replicaset"}
2023-10-26T14:36:21.180Z    DEBUG   agent/replica_set_port_manager.go:122   No port change required {"ReplicaSet": "my-namespace/mongodb-replicaset"}
2023-10-26T14:36:21.180Z    DEBUG   agent/replica_set_port_manager.go:40    Calculated process port map: map[ds042-mongodb-replicaset-0:27017]  {"ReplicaSet": "my-namespace/mongodb-replicaset"}
2023-10-26T14:36:21.180Z    DEBUG   controllers/replica_set_controller.go:537   AutomationConfigMembersThisReconciliation   {"mdb.AutomationConfigMembersThisReconciliation()": 1}
2023-10-26T14:36:21.180Z    DEBUG   controllers/replica_set_controller.go:385   Waiting for agents to reach version 3   {"ReplicaSet": "my-namespace/mongodb-replicaset"}
2023-10-26T14:36:21.180Z    DEBUG   agent/agent_readiness.go:106    The Pod 'ds042-mongodb-replicaset-0' doesn't have annotation 'agent.mongodb.com/version' yet    {"ReplicaSet": "my-namespace/mongodb-replicaset"}
2023-10-26T14:36:21.180Z    INFO    controllers/mongodb_status_options.go:110   ReplicaSet is not yet ready, retrying in 10 seconds
2023-10-26T14:36:31.064Z    INFO    controllers/replica_set_controller.go:139   Reconciling MongoDB {"ReplicaSet": "my-namespace/mongodb-replicaset"}
2023-10-26T14:36:31.064Z    DEBUG   controllers/replica_set_controller.go:141   Validating MongoDB.Spec {"ReplicaSet": "my-namespace/mongodb-replicaset"}
2023-10-26T14:36:31.064Z    DEBUG   controllers/replica_set_controller.go:151   Ensuring the service exists {"ReplicaSet": "my-namespace/mongodb-replicaset"}
2023-10-26T14:36:31.064Z    DEBUG   agent/agent_readiness.go:106    The Pod 'ds042-mongodb-replicaset-0' doesn't have annotation 'agent.mongodb.com/version' yet    {"ReplicaSet": "my-namespace/mongodb-replicaset"}
2023-10-26T14:36:31.064Z    DEBUG   agent/replica_set_port_manager.go:122   No port change required {"ReplicaSet": "my-namespace/mongodb-replicaset"}
2023-10-26T14:36:31.181Z    INFO    controllers/replica_set_controller.go:470   Create/Update operation succeeded   {"ReplicaSet": "my-namespace/mongodb-replicaset", "operation": "updated"}
2023-10-26T14:36:31.181Z    INFO    controllers/replica_set_controller.go:362   Creating/Updating AutomationConfig  {"ReplicaSet": "my-namespace/mongodb-replicaset"}
2023-10-26T14:36:31.194Z    DEBUG   scram/scram.go:172  Credentials have not changed, using credentials stored in: secret/my-scram-scram-credentials
2023-10-26T14:36:31.194Z    DEBUG   agent/agent_readiness.go:106    The Pod 'ds042-mongodb-replicaset-0' doesn't have annotation 'agent.mongodb.com/version' yet    {"ReplicaSet": "my-namespace/mongodb-replicaset"}
2023-10-26T14:36:31.194Z    DEBUG   agent/replica_set_port_manager.go:122   No port change required {"ReplicaSet": "my-namespace/mongodb-replicaset"}
2023-10-26T14:36:31.194Z    DEBUG   agent/replica_set_port_manager.go:40    Calculated process port map: map[ds042-mongodb-replicaset-0:27017]  {"ReplicaSet": "my-namespace/mongodb-replicaset"}
2023-10-26T14:36:31.194Z    DEBUG   controllers/replica_set_controller.go:537   AutomationConfigMembersThisReconciliation   {"mdb.AutomationConfigMembersThisReconciliation()": 1}
2023-10-26T14:36:31.195Z    DEBUG   controllers/replica_set_controller.go:385   Waiting for agents to reach version 3   {"ReplicaSet": "my-namespace/mongodb-replicaset"}
2023-10-26T14:36:31.195Z    DEBUG   agent/agent_readiness.go:106    The Pod 'ds042-mongodb-replicaset-0' doesn't have annotation 'agent.mongodb.com/version' yet    {"ReplicaSet": "my-namespace/mongodb-replicaset"}
2023-10-26T14:36:31.195Z    INFO    controllers/mongodb_status_options.go:110   ReplicaSet is not yet ready, retrying in 10 seconds
2023-10-26T14:36:38.234Z    INFO    controllers/replica_set_controller.go:139   Reconciling MongoDB {"ReplicaSet": "my-namespace/mongodb-replicaset"}
2023-10-26T14:36:38.234Z    DEBUG   controllers/replica_set_controller.go:141   Validating MongoDB.Spec {"ReplicaSet": "my-namespace/mongodb-replicaset"}
2023-10-26T14:36:38.235Z    DEBUG   controllers/replica_set_controller.go:151   Ensuring the service exists {"ReplicaSet": "my-namespace/mongodb-replicaset"}
2023-10-26T14:36:38.235Z    DEBUG   agent/agent_readiness.go:106    The Pod 'ds042-mongodb-replicaset-0' doesn't have annotation 'agent.mongodb.com/version' yet    {"ReplicaSet": "my-namespace/mongodb-replicaset"}
2023-10-26T14:36:38.235Z    DEBUG   agent/replica_set_port_manager.go:122   No port change required {"ReplicaSet": "my-namespace/mongodb-replicaset"}
2023-10-26T14:36:38.359Z    INFO    controllers/replica_set_controller.go:470   Create/Update operation succeeded   {"ReplicaSet": "my-namespace/mongodb-replicaset", "operation": "updated"}
2023-10-26T14:36:38.359Z    INFO    controllers/replica_set_controller.go:362   Creating/Updating AutomationConfig  {"ReplicaSet": "my-namespace/mongodb-replicaset"}
2023-10-26T14:36:38.371Z    DEBUG   scram/scram.go:172  Credentials have not changed, using credentials stored in: secret/my-scram-scram-credentials
2023-10-26T14:36:38.371Z    DEBUG   agent/agent_readiness.go:106    The Pod 'ds042-mongodb-replicaset-0' doesn't have annotation 'agent.mongodb.com/version' yet    {"ReplicaSet": "my-namespace/mongodb-replicaset"}
2023-10-26T14:36:38.371Z    DEBUG   agent/replica_set_port_manager.go:122   No port change required {"ReplicaSet": "my-namespace/mongodb-replicaset"}
2023-10-26T14:36:38.371Z    DEBUG   agent/replica_set_port_manager.go:40    Calculated process port map: map[ds042-mongodb-replicaset-0:27017]  {"ReplicaSet": "my-namespace/mongodb-replicaset"}
2023-10-26T14:36:38.371Z    DEBUG   controllers/replica_set_controller.go:537   AutomationConfigMembersThisReconciliation   {"mdb.AutomationConfigMembersThisReconciliation()": 1}
2023-10-26T14:36:38.371Z    DEBUG   controllers/replica_set_controller.go:385   Waiting for agents to reach version 3   {"ReplicaSet": "my-namespace/mongodb-replicaset"}
2023-10-26T14:36:38.371Z    DEBUG   agent/agent_readiness.go:106    The Pod 'ds042-mongodb-replicaset-0' doesn't have annotation 'agent.mongodb.com/version' yet    {"ReplicaSet": "my-namespace/mongodb-replicaset"}
2023-10-26T14:36:38.371Z    INFO    controllers/mongodb_status_options.go:110   ReplicaSet is not yet ready, retrying in 10 seconds
2023-10-26T14:36:41.203Z    INFO    controllers/replica_set_controller.go:139   Reconciling MongoDB {"ReplicaSet": "my-namespace/mongodb-replicaset"}
2023-10-26T14:36:41.203Z    DEBUG   controllers/replica_set_controller.go:141   Validating MongoDB.Spec {"ReplicaSet": "my-namespace/mongodb-replicaset"}
2023-10-26T14:36:41.203Z    DEBUG   controllers/replica_set_controller.go:151   Ensuring the service exists {"ReplicaSet": "my-namespace/mongodb-replicaset"}
2023-10-26T14:36:41.203Z    DEBUG   agent/agent_readiness.go:106    The Pod 'ds042-mongodb-replicaset-0' doesn't have
```

Answer (score 0):

@Doul Judging from the behaviour you described you're installing it in a cluster running on arm64 machine like I am on the new Macs with M1-M2 chips. I've been going mad for a while with this.
Though operator 0.8.3 has been made compatible with arm64 still has a problem.
The mongo-agent which it points to doesn't have an official arm64 image yet ( https://quay.io/repository/mongodb/mongodb-agent?tab=tags) while operator, version-upgrade-post-start-hook and readinessprobe do, so when installing mongo via the operator (the operator points to the quay.io images) the mongo-agent that gets installed is not compatible with arm64 architecture chips and mongo pods hang as `READY 1/2` with  `Readiness probe failed: command "/opt/scripts/readinessprobe" timed out` event, because the mongod container does get created but the agent doesn't.
Dough the official arm64 image for the agent is not available yet, the binaries are available and thankfully they've been built up to operator  8.0.1 by @mohsinonxrm on GitHub and made available on DockerHub see here https://github.com/mongodb/mongodb-kubernetes-operator/issues/299#issuecomment-1666717878.
So all it's needed is to override the operator chart values to use those images instead of the official at quay.io by creating a value.yaml(name it as you wish) file and install the chart with `-f path/to/the/values.yaml` flag.

values.yaml

```
operator:
  name: mongodb-kubernetes-operator
  operatorImageName: mongodb-kubernetes-operator
  deploymentName: mongodb-kubernetes-operator
  version: 0.8.1
  resources:
    limits:
      cpu: 200m 
      memory: 200Mi 
    requests:
      cpu: 200m 
      memory: 200Mi 
agent:
  name: mongodb-agent
  version: 12.0.24.7719-1
versionUpgradeHook:
  name: mongodb-kubernetes-operator-version-upgrade-post-start-hook
  version: 1.0.7
readinessProbe:
  name: mongodb-kubernetes-readiness
  version: 1.0.15

registry:
  agent: docker.io/mohsinonxrm #quay.io/mongodb
  versionUpgradeHook: docker.io/mohsinonxrm #quay.io/mongodb
  readinessProbe: docker.io/mohsinonxrm #quay.io/mongodb
  operator: docker.io/mohsinonxrm #quay.io/mongodb
```

With this I run mongo 6.0.11 on a k3d cluster on my M1 Mac.
Hopefully official arm64 image for the mongo-agent will be released soon so to use official operator 0.8.3.

Comment: No sorry, it's not on ARM64 architecture (it's Intel Xeon Gold 6242R).
I still tested with mohsinonxrm images and it fails with same errors.
So we are still blocked and we had give up on mongodb community operator. Too bad :(

Comment: Hi, I received updates about it on Github. Check here https://github.com/mongodb/mongodb-kubernetes-operator/issues/1408#issuecomment-1810012674

Comment: Thanks for the update but I'm not on ARM64 architecture :p

Comment: @Doul oh I see, I didn't catch it in your previous message lol.